# Commandline statement inside rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to execute rails commandline statement inside our rails controller

eg: I need to execute this statement

> $rails new test -d postgresql

from  my rails controller

> def index
>
> /*Code to execute the command line statement*/
>
> end

Hope am clear..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to run shell commands inside controller just use "system"

Eg:

```
system "rails new test -d postgresql"
```

or else

```
exec "rails new test -d postgresql"
```

Comment: Hi,  Am not able to create a new rails application inside the controller of existing application. I get the following error: Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first. Type 'rails' for help.

Comment: @Yothesh the error is telling you exactly what the issue is, try creating a new app in a different directory than the one you are in. I know its a super old comment, but hey it doesnt hurt

Answer (score 3):

Use backticks to shell out, like this:
    `rails new test -d postgresql`

It might be smarter to use a job queue for this.

Answer (score 3):

To run command line statements inside controller, we can use `system` command

```
system "cd {path_to_folder}; rails new test -d postgresql"
```

Answer (score 2):

Like [PradeepKumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1584224/pradeepkumar)  said (would comment on it but can't due to rep):

> system "cd {path_to_folder}; rails new test -d postgresql"

You have to declare all the commands you want to run in the same instruction (separated by a `;`). I wasn't doing so (separated the `cd` command to access the directory with my runnable and the actually execution line in two different calls) and the result I was getting was not the desired.
For example, if you try to run:

```
system "cd {path_to_folder}"
```

And then:

```
system "rails new test -d postgresql"
```

The rails command wont be executed in the context of the *path_to_folder* but in the default location for the command line interface (for instance `C:\Users\Me`) or the environment of your Rails program.

Also I was getting an error on command execution which I fixed by adding a `&` in the end of the command. In this case that the instructions has two commands, I added it in the end of the first command (before the `;`).