# Consume Sidekiq without Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm writing some calculation tasks which would be efficient in Python or Java, but Sidekiq does not seem to support external consumers.

I'm aware there's a workaround to spawn a task using system call:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(*args)
    `python script.py -c args` # and watch out using `ps`
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this with rewriting a Sidekiq consumer?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you can submit a task by creating a json using any language, but I don't see how to consume from sidekiq without `Sidekiq::Worker`.

Comment: check out this answer, never try something like this inside sidekiq, but probably can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948192/commandline-statement-inside-rails-controller

Answer (score 0):

> Sidekiq does not seem to support external consumers.

Naturally. That's what sidekiq largely *is*, a smart task/job consumer. Nothing stops you from writing an alternate consumer in python or java, though. Just make sure you play nicely with "native" sidekiq consumers.

You may have easier time pushing such specialized jobs to python-native background workers (RQ or whatever is popular).

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq uses redis to communicate with the workers. I haven't find a good documentation, so you may need to do a bit of reverse-engineering, but by using the redis queues you can implement a worker without Sidekiq.

See [How do I push a job to Sidekiq without Ruby?](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ) in the FAQ